# Total removal of contact from skype

Tags: skype

I want to totally remove any reference to an old contact in skype.  It currently is listed as "Contact Name is not in your contact list".

The only options I have are to Block, or to Add to Contacts.  I am on Windows XP and also Vista.

I do not want to re-add the contact to then remove it.

If I cannot do this from within the skype menu, is there a back-end way of totally removing the contact from the DB or Chat files on my local drive?